# Magento Magmi importer: When importing additional media_gallery images, the originals are overwritten rather than appended to

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magmi

In the Magento Magmi importer, I am trying to add extra `media_gallery` images to a product. Instead of adding extra media_gallery images to the existing one, the existing images are deleted.

My CSV is as simple as:

```
sku,media_gallery
sku1,/image1::Image label
```

I am using the latest version of Magmi, v0.7.18beta2, and the image importer plugin.

My Magmi setting s look like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what might be happening or if Magmi is capable of adding `media_gallery` images on top of existing ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- there is a **media_gallery_reset** column that is available for that.
- if not existing in datasource (or not set via value replacer or default value setter), then it is supposed to replace whole gallery with media_gallery value in datasource
- if explicitely set to 0 , then the gallery won't be reset at import and images will be added.

Comment: Thanks for this dweeves, and thanks for all your work on Magmi! :)

Comment: Hi, we have discovered that in the above scenario with the 3 columns, configurable products are changed to simple ones. Do you know why this is happening and how to fix? thanks.

Comment: This should not happen with 0.7.18beta2. it was a known bug in 0.7.17a when type column was omitted in update mode.if still happenning, just add a type column to the update csv with the product type.

Comment: Ah right, the version was actually 0.7.17a, my tests above and the actual implantation were done on different machines. thanks

Comment: @dweeves, helpful answer. One question related to this. Is there any way to replace particular media_gallery image and preserving other images in media_gallery?